# Is have any method when press action bar icon can slide menu

Tags: android, menu

Is have any method when press action bar icon can slide menu? I am not sure is need to use imageview? because I want use action bar icon.
Because I don't want use "extend fragment".

If have any one can give me some advice? I can't solve this problem.

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private String[] SlideListViewItems;
private ListView drawerListView;
DrawerLayout drawer;
Activity context;

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity.java";
private ListView listView;
String outPut;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.slidemenu);


     context=this;
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       // get slide list items from strings.xml      
     SlideListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
        //get ListView defined in activity_main.xml
    drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_slide); 
         //Set item click listener to slide list
    drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideItemAction());
          //Set the adapter for the list view
    drawerListView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.title, SlideListViewItems)); 

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
       accessWebService();
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListClickHandler());

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}


private class SlideItemAction implements OnItemClickListener{

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "draw", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
            ViewGroup vg=(ViewGroup)view;
            TextView txt=(TextView)vg.findViewById(R.id.title);
            //show selected item
            Toast.makeText(context, txt.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.v(TAG, txt.getText().toString());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use [NavigationDrawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)**

https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

It is Compatible and working on most of the devices.(Google's suggest)
And that has default beautiful icon from `MaterialDesign` and that is scrollable like this:

[image]

You won't need to use custom icon or whatever...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/DrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="7dp">


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```